# concatenating multiple columns with join in SQL

Tags: sql, outer-join

I'm trying to combine two different tables using a full outer join in SQL, but unable to identify why my SQL-query returns empty values. The SQL-code below combines Table 1 and Table 2 based on **Object** and **Date**:

```
SELECT Table1.Date_T1, Table1.Object_T1, Table1.Price_T1, Table2.Price_T2 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Object_T1 = Table2.Object_T2 
AND Table1.Date_T1=Table2.Date_T2 
UNION 
SELECT Table1.Date_T1, Table1.Object_T1, Table1.Price_T1, Table2.Price_T2
FROM Table1 
RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Object_T1 = Table2.Object_T2
AND Table1.Date_T1=Table2.Date_T2;
```

Content of the tables can seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVaH3.png), and example of the result I'm trying to created, and the actual result from the query. The query does not include the values which are only present in table 2, and not table 1.

Any advice on how i can adjust my query in order to get the corresponding date and object name for every row will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pls post sample data (and create tables script) as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was, you were selecting columns from table1 instead of table2 in your query after Union.

I selected columns from table2 and renamed it to as columns as named in table1 so as to enable it to append columns from table2 in to table1.

You can also use `Full outer join` to get result in a single join statement, if you want to eliminate the need of using Union statement. But then you would need to use `Coalesce` statement and rename the columns as per your requirement

Try this:-

```
SELECT Table1.Date_T1, Table1.Object_T1, Table1.Price_T1, Table2.Price_T2 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Object_T1 = Table2.Object_T2 
AND Table1.Date_T1=Table2.Date_T2 
UNION 
SELECT Table2.Date_T2 as Date_T1, Table2.Object_T2 AS Object_T1, 
Table1.Price_T1, Table2.Price_T2
FROM Table1 
RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Object_T1 = Table2.Object_T2
AND Table1.Date_T1=Table2.Date_T2;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It does not seem like Full outer join is supported in when using query in Excel, but changing the columns selected did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for coalesce function which returns the first non null value of a list :

```
coalesce (v1,v2,v3)
- returns v1 if not null
- otherwise returns v2 if not null
...
- otherwise returns v3



select
    coalesce(t1.date,t2.date) date_t12,
    coalesce(t1.object,t2.object) object_t12,
    t1.price_t1,
    t2.price_t2
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.date=t2.date and t1.object=t2.object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think correct answer is the one of India.Rocket.  Just for the sake of clearness, I think it should be help you to understand if you just rename the first two columns (it's not necessary to do it in second query, the one after UNION):

```
SELECT Table1.Date_T1 AS DATE_X, Table1.Object_T1 AS OBJECT_X, Table1.Price_T1, Table2.Price_T2
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Object_T1 = Table2.Object_T2 
AND Table1.Date_T1=Table2.Date_T2 
UNION 
SELECT Table2.Date_T2, Table2.Object_T2, Table1.Price_T1, Table2.Price_T2
FROM Table1 
RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Object_T1 = Table2.Object_T2
AND Table1.Date_T1=Table2.Date_T2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple joins and union,use a full join directly with coalesce function.Using COALESCE,If Table1 value is null,corresponding Table2 value can be displayed

```
   SELECT COALESCE(Table1.Date_T1,Table2.Date_T1),
COALESCE(Table1.Object_T1,Table2.Object_T1), Table1.Price_T1, Table2.Price_T2 
FROM Table1 
FULL JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Object_T1 = Table2.Object_T2 
AND Table1.Date_T1=Table2.Date_T2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Derived union table over group by

```
select 
x.[Date]
,x.[Object]
,sum(x.[Price T1]) [PriceT1]
,sum(x.[Price T2]) [PriceT2]
 from
(
SELECT Table1.Date_T1 [Date], Table1.Object_T1 [Object], Table1.Price_T1 [Price T1], 0 [Price T2]
FROM Table1 
union 
SELECT Table2.Date_T1 [Date], Table2.Object_T1 [Object], 0 [Price T1], Table2.Price_T2 [Price T2]
FROM Table2
) x 
group by 
x.[Date],x.[Object]
```